# Ratio Problems using equations

Tags: linear-algebra, ratio

Our soccer team won $\frac{2}{9}$ of its game this season. If we lost $15$ more games than we won, how many games did we play this season?  **Please give me hints DO NOT GIVE ME THE ANSWERS**  I tried to come up with an equation like $\frac{15+l+w}{w+l}=\frac{7}{9}$ This did not work out. Please give me tiny hints.

Comment: By the way, you need to change the fraction a little bit... Your approach is not wrong if you assumed $w+l$ to be matches won.

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhh ok !!!!

Comment: I changed it to $\frac{w-15+l}{w+l}=\frac{2}{9}$ It still didn't work out :(

Comment: $\frac{15+w+l}{w+l}$ is the fraction of matches lost by no of matches won... Thus the correct ratio should be $\frac{7}{2}$.... Also $\frac{w+l-15}{w+l}$ is the ratio of matches won by matches lost...so the ratio in this case should be $\frac{2}{7}$

Comment: OHHHHH $\frac{w+l-15}{w+l} = \frac{2}{7}$............ I finally got w+l=27 I got the answer right....yayayay. I technically got help from u the whole time though,,,....

Comment: You mean that $w+l=21=\text{Number of matches lost}$...... right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119734/discussion-between-nandeesh-bhatrai-and-quantumpi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Hint***

Total matches played $=9x$ (let)

Thus, matches won $=2x$ and matches lost $=7x$.

Comment: hmm ok, I'll try to work with this